# Redirect to another Rest API Url with POST data - Node Js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, httprequest, post-redirect-get

I have a payment gateway Rest API URL. so I want the redirect to the payment gateway URL from my server-side Rest API when after order details successfully saved in the database.

**Example**

example.com (Client) -> POST Request -> pay.example.com/order(Nodejs) -> redirect with POST data -> paymentgateway.com/pay/xyz (payment gateway)

so how to redirect to the payment gateway website with POST data in Express Js?.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [posting to a remote url with expressjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15409288/posting-to-a-remote-url-with-expressjs)

Comment: @kewlashu no. I don't want a response. I just want to redirect anthor website i mean payment gateway site with post data (payment details).

Comment: One way would be to render your `paymentgateway` page on the server-side, and then send the page to the client - rendering on the server side can be done with EJS (or other templating libraries). The render method allows you to pass data into the template page, which will then be rendered as HTML and sent to the client

Answer (score -3):

Have you tried:

```
res.redirect('https://app.example.io');
```

https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.redirect

Comment: Hi. yes i tried. but i want redirect with POST data. example payment details(amount,order_id,customer_name)

Comment: after post send response to browser and handle response to redirect to payment gateway.

Comment: This is not the answer! You are just sending the user to another URL and this is not how a proxy works.