# POSTing to a url in Node (working with webhooks)

Tags: node.js, shippo

I'm working on a project where I am using shippo to create shipping labels. Shippo has a webhook to allow customers to track their order statuses. I'm never used webhooks before, and I'm finding their documentation on how to set it up a bit confusing. They say to:

1. Setup a webhook.
2. `POST` the below to https://api.goshippo.com/tracks/

```
{
    "carrier": "usps",
    "tracking_number": "9102969010383081813033"
}
```

The issue that I'm having is that I'm unsure how to `POST` to a url in node. My project uses react in the frontend and node in the backend with axios being used to send my api request between the two.

I found this [posting to a remote url with expressjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15409288/posting-to-a-remote-url-with-expressjs), but the answer is from 2013, so I wasn't sure if there have been any changes since, and in general, I wasn't sure if this solution would even work for what I'm asking. I would appreciate any help or advice on how to accomplish this. Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How is an HTTP POST request made in node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6158933/how-is-an-http-post-request-made-in-node-js)

Answer (score 0):

You can post to an endpoint using the post() function in the axios module.
Syntax:

```
const axios = require("axios"); // Commonjs
axios.post( // Send POST request
    "https://api.goshippo.com/tracks/" /*URL*/,
    JSON.stringify({"carrier": "usps","tracking_number": "9102969010383081813033"}) /*body*/,
    {
        "headers": {
            "content-type":"application/json", /*indicate that the body is of type json*/
            "authorization": "ShippoToken <API_TOKEN>" /*Your api key*/
        }
    }
).then((response)=>{
    console.log(response.data); // The response in object form
    // Do what you want with the data
}).catch((error)=>{
    console.error(error); // The request failed
})
```

Edit: Changed the code to include api key